# Como fazer o botão de voltar da actionBar funcionar?

Tags: android

Eu não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar. pv me ajude.
Meu manifest está assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.alinesilvagonzaga.testedostrespontinhos">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:label="page two"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        />

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

E o método para verificar que foi tocado:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
     }
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
```

Comment: Como está o seu **onCreateOptionsMenu** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie um Intent para a case home
Exemplo:

case android.R.id.home:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity();
return true;
            return true;

Answer (score 3):

Utilize o método `setNavigationIcon` para adicionar o ícone na `Toolbar` e `setNavigationOnClickListener` para executar uma ação ao clicar no ícone.

> Método com suporte ao **Java 8** habilitado

```
    applicationToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_close_26dp);
    applicationToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(view -> finish());
```

**Observação**: o método lambda `view->finish()` só funciona se você estiver com o Java 8 habilitado.

> Método com versões posteriores ao **Java 8**

```
    applicationToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_close_26dp);
    applicationToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // ação desejada...

            }
        });
```